# Parsing Browser and OS info from the UserAgent String

Tags: javascript, web, user-agent

I need a JS code that can parse the UserAgent string and return all possible information, specifically, the browser, the browser version, and the operating system. I've had a look several sites, but they use other values of the Navigator object to return the result. While I need only to use the UserAgent.

Thank you,

Comment: If you want to do this client side you're looking at the Navigator object and it varies by client. If you want to do this server side you can look at the request headers and it's a bit more reliable/honest. Which side is this JavaScript running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't seem to recommend it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/

There is a JS library that does this on the client side; it even demos itself on its site: http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/.

It seems that [adding a particular user agent](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/commit/552915907e75e77dd0ca654999a1c60b694e036f) recognition is also easy if you have specific needs beyond what's offered.

Comment: Pretty incomplete solution. It gives "unknown" for many IE versions.

Comment: @AaronJSpetner I think it answers the original question though. Did you find a better solution? I'd be curious to know. I tried 15 random ones off here and they worked, though not always getting the OS http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:X1GmvtqmEQ8J:www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php%3Fname%3DInternet%2BExplorer+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: I've been trying a bunch. I haven't found any that are close to perfect. There was one (I'll have to find it again) that seemed to nail all the browser versions but seemed to have trouble identifying Apple OSes. Maybe the answer is for me to be less lazy and contribute to this library and fix the issues. 

Comment: Now I feel kind of silly. I was trying to use the parser to parse UA strings out of my IIS logs - but the IIS logs replace all of the spaces with "plus signs" so the RegEx in ua-parser-js was missing a bunch of them. So (as usual) it's Microsoft's fault :D

Comment: @AaronJSpetner Yeah that's not what I'd expect to get in logs either, but that would explain it. I guess you need to run each through `urldecode(log.replaceAll("+","%20"));` first?

Comment: I'm just going to replace "+" with a space.  There is no other URL encoding in the log as far as I can tell. It's just that it's a space-delimited file, so they need to do something with the spaces.